# Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, find the number of odd numbers among ${n}\choose{0}$,${n}\choose{1}$,${n}\choose{2}$, $...,$ ${n}\choose{n}$ .

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

So here is the Question :-

> Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, find the number of  odd numbers among ${n}\choose{0}$,${n}\choose{1}$,${n}\choose{2}$, $...,$${n}\choose{n}$ .

**What I Tried** :- I don't know but I guess maybe Lucas's Theorem can help doing it . It states that :-

${m}\choose{n}$ = $\prod_{i = 0}^{k}$${m_i}\choose{n_i}$ (mod p) for all:-

$m = m_kp^k + m_{k - 1}p^{k - 1} + ... + m_1p + m_0 , n = n_kp^k + n_{k - 1}p_{k - 1} + ... + n_1p + n_0$

I can use Lucas's Theorem by substituting $p = 2$ , but I am not sure how to do it, neither I am not sure whether this theorem will help or not. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Is "all" meant to be there?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A001316

Comment: "All" need not be there , I m deleting it in case that is a problem .

Comment: Since base $2$ allows only digits $0,1$, you only need to know $\binom{1}{1}, \binom{1}{0}, \binom{0}{1}, \binom{0}{0}$.

Comment: @GEdgar Ehm... What? What about $\binom{10101}{110}$? (Still in binary, of course.)

Comment: To use the Lucas formula you need only these four.  Then you multiply them together.  The result of this reasoning is the rule given in Angina's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $n=(n_kn_{k-1}\cdots n_0)_2$ in base two notation, and similarly for $n$.
The Lucas theorem implies that $\binom n m$ is odd iff every $\binom{n_i}{m_i}$
is odd, and the only way that fails is if $n_i=0$ and $m_i=1$ for some $i$.

For oddness of $\binom nm$ then $m_i$ must be zero when $n_i=0$
but $m_i$ may be zero or one when $n_i=1$. So we have two valid
choices for each $i$ with $n_i=1$, so $2^k$ valid choices overall
where $k$ is the number of ones in the base two expansion of $n$.

Comment: In the first line did u meant ? :- "Write $m = (m_km_{k - 1}...m_0)_2$ in base two notation, and similarly for n" ?

Comment: I'm writing $m$ in base two, just as you did in your question for base $p$. As an example, $39=(100111)_2$. @SouradipDas